# How do I view my previous questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I must be missing something.  How can I see a hyper linked list of titles to my previous questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of anyone else asking the same question...

Click on your name at the top of the page to go to your user profile page. Your questions and answers are listed directly underneath your profile details.